# Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 46 Click

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, xpath

I am using Selenium 2.53.0 and NetBeans JAVA code and FireFox 46

Issue: Sometimes the click method works sometimes it doesn't. I have tried the following:

Method one:

```
WebElement we = this.Driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath));
we.click();
```

Method two:

```
Narrator.logDebug(" Clicking element by Xpath : " + elementXpath);
   waitForElementByXpath(elementXpath);
   waitForElementToBeClickableByXpath(elementXpath);
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 
   ApplicationConfig.WaitTimeout());

   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(elementXpath)));
                WebElement elementToClick = 
   Driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath));
                elementToClick.click();
```

Method Three:

```
waitForElementByXpath(elementXpath);
        waitForElementToBeClickableByXpath(elementXpath);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, ApplicationConfig.WaitTimeout());
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(elementXpath)));
```

//            WebElement elementToClick = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath));

```
        WebElement we = this.Driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath));

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) Driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
```

Method Four:

```
            WebElement we = this.Driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath));
        Actions builder = new Actions(SeleniumDriverInstance.Driver);
        builder.moveToElement(we).click(we);

        builder.build().perform();

        we.click();
```

I've tried only using the ID as some of the posts that I have read, I've tried upgrading my selenium to 3+ and gecko webdriver bit then other browsers does not work.

Comment: Please provide the log trace when failed to click. Note that your methods are not equivalent: only method 3 waits until clickable, you should also wait in other methods. As for browser failure after Selenium update, that's another issue—you need to update other web-drivers too, e.g. Chrome Driver.

Comment: Issue is that the click is not "failing" it moves to the element and highlights it. Selenium thinks that the element has been click and moves to the next part of the code which then fails because the click never clicked